# inline-blocks' parent is not width of its children even though its parent is overflow-hidden

Tags: html, css

This is the code I am using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         div.ex2 {
           background-color: lightblue;
           width: 110px;
           height: 110px;
           overflow: hidden;
         }
         .cont{
         }
         .boxHolder{
            display: inline-block;
         }
         .box{
           width:100px;
           height:100px;
           background:black;
           display:inline-block;
           vertical-align:top;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="cont">
         <div class="ex2">
            <div class = "boxHolder">
               <div class = "box"></div>
               <div class = "box"></div>
               <div class = "box"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Goal is for `.boxHolder` to be width of its children combined, and its children to be inline with eachother, but for some reason it takes width of its parent even though its `inline-block` and its own parent is `overflow:hidden`.

I've also tried making it `position:absolute` But it didn't work either.

Edit:

This is how it should look like:
[image]

Edit2:

Need it without using flex.

Comment: Show a screenshot of how you want to see, pls

Answer (score 1):

Instead use flex on the `boxHolder` container and add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `box` elements, this will keep them inline and allow the horizontal overflow you want.

Additionally if you want the space between the boxes you can either add a margin-right to them, or you can use the new gap utility for flexbox but the support might not be 100% across all browsers for gap.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         div.ex2 {
           background-color: lightblue;
           width: 110px;
           height: 110px;
           overflow: hidden;
         }
         .cont{
         }
         .boxHolder{
            display: flex;
            border: 1px solid red;
         }
         .box{
           width:100px;
           height:100px;
           background:black;
           flex-shrink: 0;
           vertical-align:top;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="cont">
         <div class="ex2">
            <div class = "boxHolder">
               <div class = "box"></div>
               <div class = "box"></div>
               <div class = "box"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here's another option that's a little less... flexible than flexbox.

Set a fixed width on `boxHolder` allowing it to overflow `ex2`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         div.ex2 {
           background-color: lightblue;
           width: 110px;
           height: 110px;
           overflow: hidden;
         }
         .cont{
         }
         .boxHolder{
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 400px /*Just needs to be bigger than the cumulative width of the boxes could use calc and css vars here*/
         }
         .box{
           width:100px;
           height:100px;
           background:black;
           display: inline-block
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="cont">
         <div class="ex2">
            <div class = "boxHolder">
               <div class = "box"></div>
               <div class = "box"></div>
               <div class = "box"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited my post and added a screenshot to show what I want exactly

Comment: I updated my answer based on the image you provided.

Comment: Its not possible without display: flex?

Comment: Is there some reason you are opposed to using flex?

Comment: I had it done with flex at first, it is a part of more complex component, and some calculations were off. I had theory that flex could cause that, so I wanted to try with inline-blocks, if this would work, I'd know for sure that flex causes some miscalculations

Comment: Well you're using fixed dimensions in this example so I can't imagine how flex would calculate anything differently. But inline elements will not overflow their parent container. So if you're set on using it then the boxHolder class would need to have an explicit width set larger than it's parent to allow that overflow, otherwise inline elements wrap to the width of boxHolder which it gets from ex2.

Comment: I don't think boxHolder should get width from ex2, since its not block but an inline-block too. It should get its width from children, right? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CrfaE/11/ Though its bugged too, you can see that when 2 children are below eachother it still expands to 100% width even though its inline-block; But it works if children are side by side

Comment: That would be true, until you set a explicit width on the parent. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JHeth/qse5do84/1/)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, https://imgur.com/a/BBkTM4k 2nd behavior where empty space appears is unlogical, why does it happen? I used fixed with on parent in my example since this wont change my problem of having wrapper "page" to be width of its children, it has fixed width just so that overflow:hidden works

Comment: Clearly I'm misunderstanding you, not sure what you're trying to show in that image, no code is shown. I think maybe you're a bit confused about how display and the box model work in CSS and that misunderstanding is not something I can fix. Using flex is the best solution in this limited example, if you have a more complex component you should ask the question with that code, nobody can solve a problem they haven't seen.

Comment: Can you explain why empty space appears there and why it doesn't take width of its widest child?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220296/discussion-between-jheth-and-nick).

Comment: Oh, its the same code as the fiddle in upper comment, just resize the window

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the result you want, I had to redo your css + add pseudo-classes.

```css
div.ex2 {
           /*width: 110px;
           height: 110px;
           overflow: hidden;*/
           width: 100px;
           height: 100px;
         }
         .cont {
           background-color: lightblue;
           width: 110px;
         }
         .boxHolder{
            /*display: inline-block;*/
            display: inline-flex;
         }
         .box{
           width:100px;
           height:100px;
           /*background:black;
           display:inline-block;
           vertical-align:top;*/
           background-color: grey;
         }
         
         .box:not(:first-of-type) {
           width:120px;
           margin-left: 10px;
         }
         
         .box:first-of-type {
           background-color: black;
         }
```

```html
<div class="cont">
         <div class="ex2">
            <div class = "boxHolder">
               <div class = "box"></div>
               <div class = "box"></div>
               <div class = "box"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to discussion with @JHeth, found out that I should just use `whitespace: nowrap` on `boxHolder` component, and inline blocks will align forcing their parent that also is `inline-block` to be width of children no matter what. This allows `overflow-hidden` to work properly